# Adding required to input type date doent work

Tags: javascript, date, input, required, checkvalidity

I have a form with 4 inputs. I gave each of them "required" so the user will have to fill them in order to to finish the form.

but it seems that even though I dont insert data to the input type date, it wont show the "this field is required".
When I changed the order, and put the input type date, before the inputs type radio,
 it works!
 what could be the problem?

HTML

```
            <form action="" id="task-form">
                
                <div class="buttons-container">
                    <button class="cancel">cancel</button>
                    <button class="add-btn-inside-box" id="task-add-btn">Add</button>
                </div>
                
                <div class="title-area">
                    <h2 class="title">Title</h2>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="add a title..." id="task-title" required>
                </div>
                
                <div class="description-area">
                    <h2 class="description">Description</h2>
                    <textarea placeholder="add a title..." id="task-description" required></textarea>
                </div>
                
               

                <div class="tags-area">

                    <h2 class="tags">Tags</h2>

                    <input type="radio" id="work" name="tags" value="work" required>
                    <p class="work-tag" style="display: inline;">Work</p>

                    <input type="radio" id="study" name="tags" value="study" required>
                    <p class="study-tag" style="display: inline;" >Study</p>

                    <input type="radio" id="entertaiment" name="tags" value="Entertainment" required>
                    <p class="entertaiment-tag" style="display: inline;">Entertainment</p>

                    <input type="radio" id="family" name="tags" value="family" required>
                    <p class="family-tag" style="display: inline;">Family</p>

                </div>

                <div class="deadline">
                    <h2 for="date-task">Deadline</h2>
                    <input type="date" id="date-task" required/>
                </div>
              
                
            </form>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    
</div>
```

JS

```
const categoriesBtn = document.getElementById("categories-btn")
const allCategoriesEl = document.querySelector(".categories-options")
const plusBtn = document.getElementById("plus-btn")
const formEl = document.getElementById("task-form")
const taskContainer = document.querySelector(".task-box")
const taskCancelBtn = document.querySelector(".cancel")
const taskAddBtn = document.getElementById("task-add-btn")
const taskTitle = document.getElementById("task-title")
const taskDate = document.getElementById("date-task")
const taskDescription = document.getElementById("task-description")
const allTasksLocalStorage = bringTasksLocalStorage()


// show/hide the categories on the menu

categoriesBtn.addEventListener("click", () => allCategoriesEl.classList.toggle("categories-options-none"))

// tasks box functionality 

plusBtn.addEventListener("click", function showTaskBox() {
    taskContainer.classList.add("task-box-active")
})

taskCancelBtn.addEventListener("click", () => taskContainer.classList.remove("task-box-active"));

//main tasks box functionality:
taskAddBtn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    if(formEl.checkValidity() ){

        event.preventDefault()
    } 


    const taskTags = document.querySelector('input[name="tags"]:checked')
    const newTask = {
        Title: taskTitle.value,
        Description: taskDescription.value,
        Tag: taskTags.value,
        Date: taskDate.value
    }
```

Comment: only difference it doesn't have a `name` attribute (so probably it doesn't count as part of the form)

Comment: Fix the HTML so it [passes validation](https://validator.w3.org). Fix the javascript so it doesn't contain syntax errors (adding semicolons is also a good idea). Post the code as a runnable snippet that demonstrates the issue. As it is, minimal fixes to the HTML to make it valid show that it "works", i.e. you can't submit the form unless something has been added to the date input (some browsers might set its value to the current date). Button elements are submit buttons by default, so both the "cancel" and "task-add-btn" buttons are submit buttons.